# Double Derby DB initialization blocks Spark DataFrame creation in Jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter

When trying to create a Spark DataFrame *in a Jupyter notebook*, I get the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
```

This happens after executing this code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark.sql import Row
...
interactions_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(row_data)
```

I believe that I have tracked the problem down to double instantiation of the Derby database.  As soon as the notebook is opened, it creates 'derby.log' and 'metastore_db/' in the notebook directory.  When the code above is run, it may try to do so again.  It fills 'derby.log' with traceback and errors. Among which is:

```
...
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@23cd503e, see the next exception for details.
...
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /Users/user/src/spark-py-notebooks/nb10-sql-dataframes/metastore_db.
...
```

If I remove the 'db.lck' and 'dbex.lck' files after the notebook first loads, then I can run the code (even repeatedly) without trouble.

How I can prevent double booting of the database or get the separate attempts to talk with each other better?

I'm using Spark 2.1.0 on Yosemite OSX, jupyter 4.3.0, and starting notebook with:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter" PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark
```

I have tried other more elaborate pyspark commands (including setting --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir).  Thanks

Comment: Why do you create a separate `sqlContext` if that should be already available in jupyter/pyspark?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski In Jupyter? Unless you use Spark specific kernel, like Toree, it won't be.

Comment: The OP uses `pyspark` so _somehow_ `sc` is going to be created and hence the error. It's not a duplicate certainly. In the other answer you explain why the error may occur, but not why it occurs when jupyter/pyspark are used together. We could use the time of the OP to figure out what happens under the covers and expand our Spark knowledge.

Comment: When working manually with PySpark you have basically two choices - start context in profile (popularized by an old Cloudera guide if I am not mistaken) or initialize directly in a current notebook. Since default Python kernel is not aware of Spark, the possible resolution (don't use the same workdir, or don't use embedded database). But of course if you feel it should be reopened, just nominate it.

Comment: also not a duplicate in my opinion -- Jupyter context is the important distinction.  I will look into the 'sc'.  Maybe the sqlContext was already created with sc and can be extracted from it.  Making a DataFrame within a jupyter notebook should be a pretty common thing.  Surprised it doesn't work right.